# Can't find gst/video/colorbalance.h of gstreamer in Tinker OS V2.0.8

Tags: camera, debian, gstreamer

I am trying this code https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/playback/color-balance.html

and compile it like:

```
gcc test.c -o test1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

But it gives an error:

> test.c:4:36: fatal error: gst/video/colorbalance.h: No such file or
>   directory

and I find whole files, there is no such file indeed.

```
find ./ -name "colorbalance.h"
```

So What lib is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with "debian", on Debian systems you can use `apt-file` to find out what package contains a file:

```
$ apt-file search colorbalance.h
...
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev: /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/video/colorbalance.h
```

You need to install `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev`.